# MSP430F6638 RTC_B RTCRDY bit never set

Tags: msp430, real-time-clock

Using RTC_B

XIN is connected to a 32.768 kHz clock source (not oscillator)

XIN Bypass is used since no oscillator

Init code is as follows:

```c
//Calendar mode, BCD coded, stop rtc, hourly interrupt
RTCCTL01 = RTCTEV_0 + RTCHOLD; 

//no calibration
RTCCTL23 = 0;

//prescale setup
RTCPS0CTL = 0; // disable PS0 interrupts

//clear calendar
RTCHOUR = 0;
RTCMIN = 0;
RTCSEC = 0;
RTCDAY = 0;
RTCMON = 0;
RTCYEAR = 0;

//enable RTC
RTCCTL01 &= ~RTCHOLD;
```

After this I wait for the RTCRDY bit to get set but it never does

```c
while( !(RTCCTL01 & RTCRDY) );
```

Note that the clock is being configured as follows:

```c
// Enable XT1(32.768kHz) and XT2(4MHz) clock ports
XT1_XT2_PORT_SEL |= (XT1_ENABLE + XT2_ENABLE);
XT1_Bypass();
ret = SetVCore(3); // Set Vcore to accommodate for max. allowed 
LFXT_Start(XT1DRIVE_3);     // Enable XT1 and maximize drive strength

//! \note The system clock is derived from the internal reference clock,
//! which is set to 32768.
Init_FLL_Settle(MCLK_TICKPERSEC/1000, MCLK_TICKPERSEC/32768);
```

Comment: There is no chip with that number. Does RTCPS0 ever change? How did you configure the clock?

Comment: Corrected the typo in part.  Clock is being configured as shown in the original post (updated)

Answer (score 0):

`LFXT_Start()` disables bypass mode and enables the oscillator.